# Missing components error (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin

I tried to install Xamarin but keep getting the error:

Missing components:
Xamarin.Android is missing or out of date
Xamarin.iOS is missing or out of date
Visual Studio 2015 extension Xamarin is missing or out of date

Anyone knows what could be causing this ?

Comment: Which installation you using? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/

Comment: Diego, are you trying to install Xamarin through the VS2015 installer or with the Xamarin installer (from xamarin.com/downloads)? Can you tell us what steps you're taking to set up Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set my environment.
On your Windows developer-machine, you must have Visual Studio installed. You need to install Xamarin components in it. If you click on setup, it may ask you to update your existing installation, while updating, you must be able to select android sdk and xamarin components checkboxes.

To use Xamarin, you have to install Xamarin for Windows. 
After that Help -> about microsoft visual studio window shows below 3 things installed in list.

> Visual Studio installed components are look like as below: Xamarin
>   4.1.1.3 (34a92cd) :- Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android   6.1.1.1 (7db2aac) :- Visual Studio extension to
>   enable development for Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.iOS   9.8.1.4 (3cf8aae) :- Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS.

After that you need to make sure from VS tools menu, tools-android - android sdk manager,  you have android sdk tools and api sdk platform installed, my scrfeenshot is posted here.

[Image for Android sdk tool manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIoXt.gif)

Take a look on below very nice document - at section 5.1.1 Description, for details.
http://www.matrixguide.ch/Datenablage/diverses/Quickstart-Guide_Xamarin.pdf

Hope this helps.

Comment: The mentioned document is my document. As we have do some migrations, it was not accessible anymore. So here the new link: https://www.matrixguide.ch/PortalDokumente/diverses/Quickstart-Guide_Xamarin.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that the installation was expecting the MSI to be located in a different location that it actually was.  I simply created the folders where it was looking for them to be (even though it isn't correct), restarted the installation and the issue was resolved and the installation completed successfully.

**ERROR IN LOG** led me to identify the code was looking for 
     <%USER_HOME%>/Temp/Xamarin/download/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.3.0.784.msi

The Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.3.0.784.msi was actually located in **D:\Users\Downloads**.

In windows explorer Type **%homepath%**.  That takes you to your home directory for the currently logged in user.  I then created added \Temp\Xamarin\download.

Finally, I went back to my download on **D:\Users\Downloads** and kicked offed the installation again.

I hope this helps someone else out, it took me almost 24 and lots of uninstalling and reinstalling before I finally figured it out.